# How to check keywords in a Kotlin Collection effectively?

Tags: kotlin

I have multiple lists, which I check for some keywords and then I check

- first, if continent occurs and return `Location.EUROPE`
- and if not, check country and return `Loation.GERMANY`

Code:

```
fun getLocation(): Location {

    val listCities = listOf<City>(//..)

    val isOccurringEurope = listCities.filter{it.contains("Madrid")}.size
    if (isOccurringEurope > 0) return Location.EUROPE

    val isOccurringGermany = listCities.filter{it.contains("Hamburg")}.size
    if (isOccurringGermany > 0) return Location.GERMANY
}
```

Doing this over the size feels ineffective and I think Kotlin has a more effective way?!

EDIT:

```
data class City(val name: String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val isOccurringEurope = listCities.filter{it.contains("Madrid")}.size
if (isOccurringEurope > 0) return Location.EUROPE
```

Can be replaced by:

```
if(listCities.contains("Madrid")) return Location.EUROPE
```

The `.filter` will create another list with only the elements that contain "Madrid", and then you are checking the size of that. That is a bit redundant. But there is a caveat, if you have a multi word name, like `The Hague`, and you search for `Hague`, you won't get it any more. If you want ot take this into account, I'd do this:

```
if(listCities.any {it.contains("Hague", true)}) return Location.EUROPE
```

This one will match both `The Hague`, `Hague`, `hague`, `the city of hague`, etc. Note, the `true` at the end is optional, and it means that it will ignore differences in case (`A` will be the same a `a`), it can be removed if not needed.

Since the addition of the `City` object, you can just do:

```
listCities.any {it.name.contains("Hague", true)}
```

or, for the simple version:

```
listCities.any {it.name == "Hague"}
```

Comment: I've edited the answer accordingly. Baftă (good luck).

Comment: I tried to keep the exmaple as simple as possible. The problem I have is the list is of type List<City> whereas City is edited above. So elements are of type City and not as easy to do so

Comment: yes it still is simple, replace the `listCities.any {it.contains("Hague", true)}` with `listCities.any { it.name.contains("Hahue", true)}` change the `name` to your actual property name. Or you could even do `listCitites.any {it.name == "Hague}` for the simple version. I've edited the answer as well.

Comment: @Alex.T I think you should update your answer to fit the new requirements

Comment: @Joffrey it should be there now, the last 2 ones with `it.name`

Comment: @Alex.T My bad, I didn't see the last part.